# Add User To Group After Signup AWS-Cognito (Android)

Tags: amazon-cognito

After signing up a new user , I would like to add that user to an existing Cognito Group . Is this possible in android?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly mention more details about your environment, including programming language, detailed use-case, and functionality. To give a quick answer to your question in a broad sense, the answer is yes. However, Android development can be performed using a large array of languages/frameworks, and not all of them have full-fledged AWS SDKs. Kindly consider improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the API you can call to add a user to a group - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminAddUserToGroup.html

In the Android AWS SDK, you can call this api.
Here's some documentation on using the Android SDK to call cognito -https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-android-sdk-with-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/

Just simply call the aforementioned api to add a user to a group

Comment: Thanks for information. I have added below code snippet but i don't know how to add these into Aws Cognito class                                                                                       var addUserToGroupRequest =  AdminAddUserToGroupRequest()
              .withGroupName(groupname)
              .withUserPoolId(poolid)
              .withUsername(username);